# Windows Powershell ISE find text in console pane

Tags: windows, powershell, console

I'm new to Windows Powershell and I'm using the ISE (Integrated Scripting Environment) because someone recommended it. One thing that I don't know how to do is find text (Ctrl+F) in the console pane. I know it's possible in the scripting pane, but the functionality is greyed out in the console pane. Is finding text possible at all in the console pane in the Powershell ISE?

Comment: No. you can't search the output buffer from what I know.

Comment: Oh wow that is ridiculous.

Comment: `Ctrl+Left`, `Ctrl+A`, `Ctrl+C`, `Ctrl+N`, `Ctrl+V`, `Ctrl+Home`, `Ctrl+F`

Comment: That. Is. Hilarious.